# zsh script not printing output of "jobs" command?

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

This examples works on my zsh terminal, but not in the context of my zsh script:

```
sh -c 'sleep 15 && echo asdf' &
x=$(jobs)
echo $x
```

Works as expected on commandline (outputs `[1]  + running    sh -c 'sleep 15 && echo asdf'`)

But the following script does not print:

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh 
sh -c 'sleep 3 && echo hi' & sh -c 'sleep 5 && echo bye' &
while (( ${#jobstates} )); do
  sleep 1;
  x=$(jobs)
  echo $x          #DOES NOT print to stdout
  jobs             #DOES print to stdout
  jobs | grep "hi" #DOES NOT print to stdout
  y=$(ls)
  echo $y          #DOES print to stdout
done
```

Why is `jobs` in the middle of a loop special in any way?

Context of what I'm trying to do: I'm just trying to check on my launched jobs so I can query things about them while I am waiting for them to complete / when they have completed.

Answer (score 0):

*No experience with zsh, but on a general level:*

1. Have you verified that `$(jobs)` actually generates output? *(btw: i'd enclose it in `"`)*
2. ... and the same may be the problem with `jobs | grep "hi"` *(no `hi` in the output of `jobs`)*

Comment: 1. Yes, $(jobs) on command line generates output but not in script. 2. Tried already. Seems to function identically.

Answer (score 0):

I think `jobs` writes directly to the terminal (and not to stdout) under certain circumstances because it is assumed that it's only useful in interactive context. This behavior is probably hard-coded.

On my system (`zsh 5.9.0.1-dev` on Arch Linux) I succeeded with this ugly hack to put the output of jobs into a shell variable:

```
temp_file=$(mktemp)
jobs > $temp_file
x=$(< $temp_file)
print $x
rm $temp_file
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up running with this workaround as well and it works. jobs > file.log and then do stuff with 'cat file.log' to query information about the jobs. (I've also tried the same with `job -r` in bash, but for some reason running it on bash has the expected behavior)

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with this solution without temp file:

```
function debounce_sync() {
    sleep 10
    echo "after 10 secs!!!"
}

unset last_pid
while read; do
    if [[ -v last_pid ]]; then
        kill -9 $last_pid >/dev/null 2>&1
    fi
    debounce_sync &
    last_pid=$!
done
unset last_pid
```

pid of last launched job is stored in `$!`

You can store them in array variable or just kill previous to keep only single running job